# Exception:"attempt to access org.rosuda.REngine.REXPGenericVector as String"

Tags: java, r, exception, eval

I have the following function to read a csv(having 18000 rows and 21 columns) and display its content in java console.

```
public void rFun() {

    Rsession instance = RConnect.getInstance();

    instance.eval("load(\".RData\")");

    instance.eval("g <- read.csv(\"Book2.csv\")");

    REXP x = instance.eval("hh <- head(g,2)");

    REXP x1 = instance.eval("nrow(hh)");
    REXP x2 = instance.eval("ncol(hh)");
    try {


        int i = 0;  
        for(int j=0; j<x1.asInteger(); j++){
                for(int k=0; k<x2.asInteger(); k++){
            System.out.println("Element ["+(j+1)+"]["+(k+1)+"] = "+x.asStrings()[i]);
                i++;
                }
            }

    } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But when I execute this function I am getting this exception:
attempt to access org.rosuda.REngine.REXPGenericVector as String.
This piece of code is working for if I create a data frame like below:

```
instance.eval("xyz <- matrix(c(10,20,3,\"A\",40,50,60),nrow=2)");             
REXP x = instance.eval("df <- as.data.frame(xyz)");
```

I tried converting the data type of each column to character and then retrieve the value but same exception is thrown. Please help.

Comment: A long shot, but could it be the lack of double `\\` for filenames?

Comment: No. It's reading the file properly and displaying it's row/column counts as well as class,colnames etc properly.

Comment: I have the same problem.
It seems data frames are returned as RExpGenericVectors, and that class doesn't have a string representation.
The same happens with lists.
list1 <- list(c(2,5,3),21.3,sin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
for(int i=1; i<=x1.asInteger(); i++){
    for(int j=1; j<=x2.asInteger(); j++){
                     REXP cls1 = instance.eval("c1 <- h["+i+","+j+"]");
                     System.out.println(cls1.asString());
    }
}
```

No need of converting the data type to character. Hope it helps.